# Postgres in Node INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to do an Insert with an update on conflict in node into a postgres database.
For this i am using the pg node library. I have the following query object:

```
const query = {
        text: 'INSERT INTO table(id, x, y) VALUES($1, $2, $3) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET x = ($2), y = ($3);',
        values: [1, 'x', 'y']
    };

client.query(query.....
```

Then i just do client.query(query.....

But its not working, is there a problem with the sql syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo-table `EXCLUDED` to access the values in the `DO UPDATE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO table(id, x, y) 
VALUES($1, $2, $3) 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET x = EXCLUDED.x, y = EXCLUDED.y
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it is not working as well, do you have a second idea maybe?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by *not working*.